# What words I can use for constant in this context?

Tags: word-request

I want to use a word which means constant in this context, which is kind of in negative sense

> Opportunities/prospects, in the beginning, in this company are massive,  but after a few years growth will be constant.

Basically what I am trying to imply is that after sometime things will be very boring with no new opportunities just the same thing over and over again. Synonyms of constant like steady, stable don't really work for me as they have, in my opinion, positive connotation while I want words with negative connotation?

Comment: A synonym for *constant* will not give a more negative meaning. No doubt there are many possible negative words you could plug in, just pick one. But it might be OK to just change *but* to a more contrasting term, like *however* or *unfortunately*.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if "constant growth" captures your meaning. Growth, in the sense of career opportunities, is generally a positive thing. Exponential or rapid growth is very good, but [constant](http://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/american/constant), or steady, growth is also good. Not growing, or stagnating in your career is negative.

I think you might be looking for a word more like [stagnant](http://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/american/stagnant) or [dwindle](http://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/american/dwindle).

The suggestion in the comments to replace "but" with "however" or "unfortunately" is a good one. I might rephrase your sentence as:

> In the beginning, the opportunities in this company are massive, however, after a few years the number of new opportunities dwindles to almost nothing.